# Visual Studio 2022 slow loading of ReSharper extension

Tags: resharper, visual-studio-2022

How can I improve the loading of the Resharper extension in Visual Studio 2022 Comunity when opening a new solution? I have a good computer (AMD ryzan 7, 32gb ram, 1tb ssd)

I expect it to load in 5 seconds maximum, not in 30 seconds

Comment: Try https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Reference__Options__Environment__Performance_Guide.html . Resharper's performance has improved over the years but it'll never be as fast as VS without it.